# Usar página php con Node.js

Tags: php, mysql, nodejs

uso un servidor compartido con `node.js`, siempre programo con `php` pero quisiera tener un chat en tiempo real con las posibilidades que ofrece node.js. Mi pregunta es cómo lograrlo sin desperdiciar todo el trabajo que se hizo en php. Por ejemplo, quiero mostrar esta página con node.js usando el archivo php en sí, esta página la llamaré `index.php`:

```
<?php 
  $mysql = new mysqli("hostingcompartido", "juan", "juan123", "usuarios");
  if ($mysql->connect_error) die('Problemas con la conexion a la base de datos');

  $mysql->set_charset("utf8");

$datosusuario = $mysql->query("select * from usuarios where cod=1") or die($mysql->error);
    if ($datosusuari = $datosusuario->fetch_array()){
      echo $datosusuari['nombre'];
    }
?>
```

Mi directorio sería algo como esto:

```
Node_js->app.js
         package.js
         Paginas php->index.php
```

Comment: Nodejs no compila PHP. Lo que tendrías que hacer es ejecutar desde Nodejs el comando `php` para compilar el archivo (_y enviar los parámetros_) y al resultado obtenido mostrarlo.

Comment: Y cómo se hace eso desde un alojamiento compartido?